# Pandas plotting pyplot not showing graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot weekly stock data using a `for` loop. My code is as follows, but my graph is incorrect.

```
for x in range(0, max(stock['week']) + 1):
    print(x)
    df = stock[stock.week == x]
    plt.plot(x = df['new_date'], y = df['Low'], linewidth=5, color = [0, 0, 1])
    print(df)
    # df.plot(x = df['new_date'], y=df['Low'])
    plt.savefig('weekGraph/' + str(x) + '.png')
```

My graph look like this [I am getting a graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52eZM.png)

I am new to python. Where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: Yes i pull that stock data using nsepy library

Comment: Is there a folder "weekGraph" in your working directory?

Comment: yes i have the folder

Comment: Everything looks quite OK from this side then, must be the problem in your `stock` data. Or, perhaps they are just null valued(or very small values such that they cannot be shown in a graph??)

Comment: its a weekly stock data which contain the date and the closing price. 5 data points per week. i want to plot closing price/lowest price against date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For once replace this line
`plt.plot(x = df['new_date'], y = df['Low'], linewidth=5, color = [0, 0, 1])`

with:

`plt.plot(df['new_date'], df['Low'], linewidth=5, color = [0, 0, 1])` and see if it works. Everything else looks quite ok from this side.